# Splash Screen Activity

Tags: android, handler, splash-screen

I added splash screen to my application and my code looks as follow:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int DELAY_MILLIS = 2000;//for testing i use 5 seconds
    private Handler handler = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, CurrencyExchangeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, DELAY_MILLIS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
}
```

My Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vdovin.currencyratesapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:name=".application.CurrencyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".screens.splash.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".screens.main.CurrencyExchangeActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

So I faced with next problem:

If I hide my app with home button when loading splash screen, then when I open app again, splash screen activity not call `CurrencyExchangeActivity`. I understand that it appears because method `onCreate()` invoked only once, but I can't put it in `onResume()` because when I open my app again it shows me the splash screen again. But I want to show `CurrencyActivity`, like google's apps(maps, sheets etc...)

Comment: Add your manifest file too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that simply because you're setting the splash screen image as `background` of `theme` of your `Activity`. That's window level background which would show up regardless of your navigation or anything.

If you really want to show splash screen only once in app lifetime then you'll have to do it in `not the right way` and have that image as part of your layout and inflate that layout using `setContentView`. Now when you come again in the app, you will call your `CurrencyExchangeActivity` even before `setContentView` of `splash activity` and which will just show a black window background and directly show up `CurrencyExchangeActivity`.

Let me know if this makes sense or not. I can elaborate more if needed

Comment: Do you think that google also make it in not right way?

Comment: Google maps shows splash screen everytime! Same goes for google sheets app. it's background in the theme.

Comment: @Vdovin the problem you're facing is that, you're adding extra delay manually which you shouldn't. It would just work without any delay.

Comment: Hmm, i replace postDelay with post and seem it work as i want. But it's good to show splash for a such little time?And what's best practice with splash screen?

Comment: @Vdovin Yes. That's exactly how much time it should be shown. It's more for your app branding. In that case, it's best practice to have it as background. Follow material design guidelines here for more information on branding piece.

Comment: @Vdovin Also, why are you doing post also ? Just directly create `intent` and start it and `finish` this activity

Comment: It was a pity to part with handler:D Yes, it's my mistake) Changed it

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way. I haven't tested your code. My sway of using the splash will be like below:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = SplashActivity.class.getSimpleName();
Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        loadNext();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);


    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
        }
    }.start();
}


protected void loadNext() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it isn't work for me. After 5 second it will open CurrencyActivity automatically.

Comment: "splash screen activity not call CurrencyExchangeActivity" I thought u have problem in navigation to currencyExchangeactivity

Comment: No, it not call Currency Exchange Activity because method onCreate invoked only once and i remove callbacks from handler in onStop, so I when i open app again, i don't invoke onCreate, but i wrote why i don't put handler in onResume

Answer (score 0):

you have forgot to add

`setContentView(R.layout.splash);`

add this it will work

Comment: I do it through layer. https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try the following:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CurrencyExchangeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

This will skip the delay when reopening the app after pressing the home button.

Comment: I i hide app with home button and open it again. I see splash screen again, but i want to see CurrencyActivity

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a postDelayed Runnable.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // 5 sec
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // 5 sec
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: If i hide app when loading splash screen and open it again, i will see splash screen again. So it's don't work for me

Comment: You haven't this problem if you postdelay runnable in onResume(). The bug in your code is ti run runnable onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest to keep the splash screen showing mechanism in the `CurrencyActivity` in your case. Here's the pseudo code.

I've added proper comments in the code. Please check.

```
public class CurrencyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int DELAY_MILLIS = 2000; //for testing i use 5 seconds
    private Handler handler = null;
    private boolean showSplash = true; // True by default
    private ImageView splashImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.currency_activity);

        // Get a image overlaying the other views in your currency layout
        splashImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash);

        if(showSplash) showSplashScreen();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        showSplash = false; // Set the variable to false when you take this in background
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Check if the variable is false and then set the visibility to GONE
        if(!showSplash) splashImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private void showSplashScreen() {
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                splashImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                showSplash = false;
            }
        }, DELAY_MILLIS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out--

SplashScreenActivity-

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final int DELAY_MILLIS = 2000;//for testing i use 5 seconds

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, CurrencyExchangeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }, DELAY_MILLIS);
}
```

}

For manifest--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".CurrencyExchangeActivity"/>




</application>
```

i tested this code for if you had the problem that when the home screen button is pressed the splash screen is displayed again then this would work....